# How to get Inner repeater Label Control in Outer Repeater's ItemDataBound

Tags: c#, .net

I have Nested Repeater.
I binded inner repeater in outer repeater's ItemDataBound.

```
protected void rptrOuter_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {
 Repeater rptrInner = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("rptrInner ");
  List<String> objList = new List<String>();
            objList = GetListofData().ToList();
 rptrInner .DataSource = objList ;
            rptrInner .DataBind();
   Label lblName = rptrInner .FindControl("lblName") as Label;
//Error Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

}
```

Even i tried  `Label lblName = e.Item.FindControl("lblName") as Label;`

in single repeater will get label like

```
Label lblId= e.Item.FindControl("lblId") as Label;
```

Like this how can i get nested repeater's Label inside outer repeater??

Please help me...

Comment: What problem are you trying to resolve?

Comment: I need to set label's text. Label is there inside inner repeater. I dont want to use inner repeater's itemdatabound.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to locate the inner repeater using the event arguments. If it's contained in the outer repeater and that's what's raising the event, it should be contained in the sender. I'm not 100% on how the syntax would look, but going off of what you wrote, try something like this:

```
Repeater rptrInner = ((Repeater)sender).FindControl("rptrInner");
```

Comment: Sorry, my misunderstanding :) where is `rptrProductTakenList` coming from?

Comment: So the label is inside of the inner repeater?

Comment: Yes. In single repeater we can use like: Label lblId= e.Item.FindControl("lblId") as Label;

Comment: Okay. If what you're experiencing is a null reference exception, I would expect that similar to what I mentioned, you're setting `rptrInner` to the event arguments. Though I'm not sure if it would cause an error sooner than it did if that's the case or not. Have you tried using `sender` instead of `e` when setting up `rptrInner`?

Comment: By doing Repeater rptrInner = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("rptrInner "); I can bind to inner repeater. Here my problem is no to bind. I want to get Label Control of inner repeater in outer repeater's data bound.